How to restore SSAS .db from folder backup
I couldn't connect to (microsoft analysis service) SSAS from SSMS because it threw some errors with old databases.
I followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159973/ssas-errors-in-the-metadata-file-error-trying-to-u

Stop SSAS service Make backup of project: C:\Program Files\Microsoft
SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\MyProject.0.db Delete SSAS
database.  So delete contents of C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\MyProject.0.db directory.  Copy
0.CryptKey.bin file from backup to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\MyProject.0.db Start SSAS service
and deplot/process your cube again using BID

backed up the .db folder and deleted the content, it worked and I was able to access the server from SSMS.
Now I want to restore the backup, simply copy pasting the folder doesn't seem to work, I already tried to stop and restart the service.
how do I restore them? I cannot just rebuild them because I believe the code was lost long ago.
